Convert complex js objects with files to FormData
I have a complex object with nested objects and arrays (of objects)
In the objects, that are in the Arrays, can be files.
I use Axios to send the data and everything, except the Files, works fine when I send my object to my API.
To upload also files, I tried to convert my object into FormData
static patch(url, data, options, config) {
    // Immer FormData verwenden
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Rekursive Funktion zum Hinzufügen von Daten zu FormData
    const appendToFormData = (formData, data, parentKey) => {
      if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        data.forEach((value, index) => {
          appendToFormData(formData, value, `${parentKey}[${index}]`);
        });
      } else if (data && typeof data === 'object' && !(data instanceof File)) {
        Object.keys(data).forEach((key) => {
          if (parentKey) {
            appendToFormData(formData, data[key], `${parentKey}.${key}`);
          } else {
            appendToFormData(formData, data[key], key);
          }
        });
      } else if (data !== undefined && data !== null) {
        formData.append(parentKey, data);
      }
    };

    // Daten zu formData hinzufügen
    appendToFormData(formData, data);

    // Konfiguration für Axios
    config = {
      ...config,
      headers: {
        ...config?.headers,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };

    return this.handleResponse(
      this.getInstance().patch(url, formData, config),
      options
    );
  }

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, but make it worse. The nested Arrays did not update anymore.
The API is build with Djano rest-framework and uses the FileField in the model to upload Files.
Can someone help me?
